# Suddenly App Service stopped working because of exception Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights'

Tags: azure

Our Azure Web App Service in production was working fine and suddenly on 15 November exactly at 019-11-15 06:22:56.2653 we saw the app service being down due to the following error. We have not changed anything neither deployed anything new on the said app service. Wanted to know if there was any upgrade from Microsoft which caused this?

ERROR|Stopped program because of exception Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=2.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Also, looking at the error we took new nuget package for appinsight and deployed and it seems to be working fine. But wanted to know what caused this and how can we prevent this in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually an [pre-release of Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, version 2.12.0-beta2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/2.12.0-beta2) on 15 November. But this should does nothing to do with your issue.

You should nav to your azure web site -> [kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/11/08/how-to-access-kudu-scm-for-an-azure-app-service-environment-ase/), to see if the specified dll is removed by accident.